# Получить данные из таблицы в переменную

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день.

Проблема в следующем:

Нужно получить из таблицы users значение поля group, и если значение равно 1, то загрузить шаблон меню для пользователя, а если значение 2, то загрузить шаблон меню для админа. То ли неправильно формирую запрос, то ли есть какой-то подвох.

Код примерно следующий:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?php
session_start();
include ("bd.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT group FROM users");
$user_group = mysql_fetch_row($result);
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Заказ комплексных обедов с доставкой</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php       
require 'tpl/sablon.php';
if ($user_group = 1)
{
require 'bloks/menu.php';   
}
if ($user_group = 2)
    {
require 'bloks/menu2.php';
}
?>  
<div id="content">
<h1>Вход на сайт</h1>
<form action="testreg.php" method="POST">
<p>
<label>Ваш логин<br></label>
<input name="login" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>
<p>
<label>Ваш пароль<br></label>
<input name="password" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
<a href="reg.php">Зарегистрироваться</a>
</p>
</form>
<br>
<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['login']) or empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
echo "Вы вошли на сайт, как гость<br><a href='#'>Эта ссылка  доступна только зарегистрированным пользователям</a>";
}
else
{
echo "Вы вошли на сайт, как ".$_SESSION['login']."(<a    href='exit.php'>выход</a>)<br>";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Samurai, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам класс правильный пример для работы с бд

```
    include 'registry.php';
    class DataBase {

    public function Connect()
    {
        try {
            $user = 'ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ_БД'; //!
            $dbname = 'ИМЯ_БД'; //!
            $pass = 'ПАРОЛЬ'; //!
            $options = array( PDO:: MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
            $con = Registry::set('DBH', new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=" . $dbname . "", $user, $pass, $options));
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); // репортим ошибки
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

   public function Disconnect() {
      $DBH = null;
   }

}

class MyClassForTable extends DataBase {

    public static function LoadFromTable(){
        $DBH = Registry::get('DBH');
        $STH = $DBH ->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ" );  // заменить на имя таблицы
        $STH->execute();
        $result = $STH->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }
}

$db = new database(); // Создаем экземпляр класса
$db->Connect(); // Вызываем метод для подключения
$data = MyClassForTable::MyClassForTable(); // Забираем данные из таблицы в $data
var_dump($data); // Выводим $data
$db->Disconnect(); // закрываем соединение
```

Код паттерна реестр (registry.php) можно забрать вот тут. http://ideone.com/Yag3ki