# Вывод информации о юзере из БД

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Как лучше всего выводить информацию о конкретном юзере из бд?
К примеру, его логин, пароль, дату рождения.

```
fetchrow`ом
```

Или есть аналоги данной "операции"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать PDO:

```
public static function LoadFromTable($id){
        $DBH = Registry::get('DBH');
        $STH = $DBH ->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");  // забираем информацию о юзере по id
        $STH->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); // или PARAM_INT
        $STH->execute();
        $result = $STH->fetchAll();
        return $result; // вернет ассоциативный массив
    }
```

Более подробно посмотреть на мой ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408977#408988), ну и не забываем про оф. документацию php.net [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Перед тем, как копипастить ответ, посмотри - правильно ли ты стырил его.  
Никто не сказал, что это будет метод объекта (хотя надо бы), а так же непонятно, что за `Registry::get('DBH')` (хотя догадаться можно).

Comment: о_О откуда стырил?

Answer (score 3):

Шта?
Выбирай с помощью `select`, забирай из объекта ответа через `fetch` - это если через PDO.